# Why does AngularJS with ui-router keep firing the $stateChangeStart event?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to block all ui-router state changes until I've authenticated the user:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, toParams) {
  if (!authenticated) {
    event.preventDefault()
    //following $timeout is emulating a backend $http.get('/auth/') request
    $timeout(function() {
      authenticated = true
      $state.go(next,toParams)
    },1000)
  }
})
```

I reject all state changes until the user has been authenticated, but if I go to an invalid URL that uses the `otherwise()` configuration, I get an infinite loop with a message:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 7; oldVal: 6"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 8; oldVal: 7"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10"]]
```

Below is my [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Serve it up with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7070` and go to `localhost:7070/test.html#/bar` to see it explode in your face.  Whereas directly navigating to the only valid angularjs location does not blow up `localhost:7070/test.html#/foo`:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="clientApp">
    <div ui-view="" ></div>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('clientApp', ['ui.router'])

      var myRouteProvider = [
                '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider) { 
          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/foo');
          $stateProvider.state('/foo', {
            url: '/foo',
            template: '<div>In Foo now</div>',
            reloadOnSearch: false
          })
        }]
      app.config(myRouteProvider)

      var authenticated = false
      app.run([
                 '$rootScope', '$log','$state','$timeout',
        function ($rootScope,   $log,  $state,  $timeout) {
          $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, toParams) {
            if (!authenticated) {
              event.preventDefault()
              //following $timeout is emulating a backend $http.get('/auth/') request
              $timeout(function() {
                authenticated = true
                $state.go(next,toParams)
              },1000)
            }
          })
        }
      ])
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there an alternative method I should use to accomplish this authentication blocking?  I do realize this authentication blocking is client side only.  I'm not showing the server side of things in this example.

Comment: This isn't a direct solution to your question, but you should checkout [this article](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec) about different auth techniques in Angular.  One of the sections shows how to implement with uiRouter and `$stateProvider`.

Comment: Thank you Terry.  I'm actually using a bastardized version of that exact article for my authentication, which is probably my issue.  I just reduced my code to the above in order to post it on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fakeout.  This is an interaction issue between `$urlRouterProvider`  and `$stateProvider`.  I shouldn't be using `$urlRouterProvider` for my `otherwise`.  I should be using something like:

```
$stateProvider.state("otherwise", {
    url: "*path",
    template: "Invalid Location",
    controller: [
              '$timeout','$state',
      function($timeout,  $state ) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $state.go('/foo')
        },2000)
      }]
});
```

Or even a transparent'ish redirect:

```
$stateProvider.state("otherwise", {
    url: "*path",
    template: "",
    controller: [
              '$state',
      function($state) {
        $state.go('/foo')
      }]
});
```

Altogether now:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="clientApp">
    <div ui-view="" ></div>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('clientApp', ['ui.router'])

      var myRouteProvider = [
                '$stateProvider',
        function($stateProvider) { 

          $stateProvider.state('/foo', {
            url: '/foo',
            template: '<div>In Foo now</div>',
            reloadOnSearch: false
          })

          $stateProvider.state("otherwise", {
              url: "*path",
              template: "",
              controller: [
                        '$state',
                function($state) {
                  $state.go('/foo')
                }]
          });
        }]
      app.config(myRouteProvider)

      var authenticated = false
      app.run([
                 '$rootScope', '$log','$state','$timeout',
        function ($rootScope,   $log,  $state,  $timeout) {
          $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, toParams) {
            if (!authenticated) {
              event.preventDefault()
              //following $timeout is emulating a backend $http.get('/auth/') request
              $timeout(function() {
                authenticated = true
                $state.go(next,toParams)
              },1000)
            }
          })
        }
      ])
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you save my life with this state called "otherwise" =)

Comment: I already had an otherwise. For me, the fix was to make a state called default that had a url of '' that set a $state.go('home') in the controller.

Answer (score 48):

Looks like this is a bug with ui-router when you use the combination of $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/foo) with the $stateChangeStart.

Issue - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/600

Frank Wallis provides a nice workaround, use the longer form of the otherwise method that takes a function as an argument:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise( function($injector, $location) {
            var $state = $injector.get("$state");
            $state.go("app.home");
        });
```

Nice work Frank!

Comment: I wish I found this post a day earlier ! I've tried Ross' solution but yours did the trick, thanks a ton !

Comment: I believe this is the correct fix based on the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes).

Comment: Worked perfectly. just the solution i needed. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue. Below is the code to workaround, which inspired by [angular-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission/blob/master/dist/angular-permission.js) project.

The main concept is to add a flag(`$$finishAuthorize`) into state manually, and break the infinite loop by this flag. Another point we need to be aware is the `{notify: false}` option of `$state.go`, and broadcast `"$stateChangeSuccess"` event manually.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.$$finishAuthorize) {
        return;
    }
    if (!authenticated) {
        event.preventDefault();
        toState = angular.extend({'$$finishAuthorize': true}, toState);

        // following $timeout is emulating a backend $http.get('/auth/') request
        $timeout(function() {
            authenticated = true;
            $state.go(toState.name, toParams, {notify: false}).then(function() {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams);
            });
        },1000)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. Turns out it was the code that they suggested to make a trailing slash optional at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
  var path = $location.url();

  console.log(path);
  // check to see if the path already has a slash where it should be
  if (path[path.length - 1] === '/' || path.indexOf('/?') > -1) {
    return;
  }

  if (path.indexOf('?') > -1) {
    return path.replace('?', '/?');
  }

  return path + '/';
});
```

changed this to

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
  var path = $location.url();
  // check to see if the path already has a slash where it should be
  if (path[path.length - 1] === '/' || path.indexOf('/?') > -1) {
    return;
  }
  if (path.indexOf('?') > -1) {
    $location.replace().path(path.replace('?', '/?'));
  }
  $location.replace().path(path + '/');
});
```

not returning the new path and just replacing it doesn't trigger a StateChangeStart

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your run block to this:

```
    app.run([
             '$rootScope', '$log','$state','$interval',
    function ($rootScope,   $log,  $state,  $interval) {
      var authenticated = false;
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, toParams) {
        if (!authenticated) {
          event.preventDefault()
          //following $timeout is emulating a backend $http.get('/auth/') request
        }
      })


      var intervalCanceller = $interval(function() {
        //backend call
        if(call succeeds & user authenticated) {
          authenticated = true;
          $interval.cancel(intervalCanceller);
          $state.go(next, toParams);
        }
      }, 3000);
    }
  ])
```

Comment: Did you give that a try?  When I do what you suggested, it still fails.  The original `$timeout` doesn't even fire before the error shows up, so I'm not quite sure how `$interval` firing the function more than once will help.  Also, if the `$stateChangeStart` callback function terminates immediately, the state will change.  I don't need to call `$state.go()` as doing nothing at all in the function should cause the state to transition.

Comment: Blocks of code don't format well in comments.  Want to put that in your original answer?  Just click `edit` above.

Comment: @Ross Rogers :Don't call $state.go inside stageChange event handler. That's the reason why it is going in loop.

Comment: Neeraj, did you give that a try in context? My original code doesn't even call the `$state.go()` function before the error is thrown.  If I comment out the `$state.go()` completely, it still fails.

Comment: Check this out: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jm5JG9Ydm5qS3GSW2jWR. Tell me if it solves your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the essence of this problem has to do with `$location`/`window.location` manipulation, so embedding that into a plnkr doesn't exhibit the issue.  If I copy and paste your solution into a file and then serve it up on a webserver ( e.g. python's SimpleHTTPServer), then your code still fails.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions, with varying degrees of success (am building an Ionic cordova application). At one point I managed to not get infinite loops and the state would change but I was left with a blank view. I added `{ reload:true }` and it seems to help. I tried with `{ notify:false }` and `{ notify: true }` and that did not help.

I ended up using most of the answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26800804/409864

```js
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

  // Do not redirect if going to an error page
  if (toState.name === 'app.error') {
    return;
  }

  // Do not redirect if going to the login page
  if (toState.name === 'app.login') {
    return;
  }

  // Do not redirect if there is a token present in localstorage
  var authData = localstorage.getItem('auth');
  if (authData.token) {
    return;
  }

  // We do not have a token, are not going to the login or error pages, time to redirect!
  event.preventDefault();
  console.debug('No auth credentials in localstorage, redirecting to login page');
  $state.go('engineerApp.home', {}, {reload: true}); // Empty object is params
});
```