# Ui-Router $state.go inside $on('$stateChangeStart') is cauzing an infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to introduce login into the way the user navigates accross the application.

I pretend to redirect the user to the page were he was before he navigate to the login page if that page meets specific requirements

Preventing the event from the $stateChangeStart stop's the state change like expected but when i run the $state.go('into_somewhere') i enter an infinit loop

My angular version is 1.3.1 and the ui-router is the latest

```
.factory('RouteHistory', function ($rootScope,$log, $state, Auth, $urlRouter, $timeout) {

    // after the user enter a page
    var currentState = '';

    // when the user is trying to access a page that he has not permissions
    // or that requires the user to be logged in
    var pendingState = '';

    var isMenuTogglerVisible = false;
    var skipFromStateVal = true;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

      event.preventDefault();



      if (toState.name == 'login' && fromState.name != 'login'){
        $log.log('Ui-router: changing to login');
        // $urlRouter.sync();
        $state.go('login')
        //pendingState = fromState;
        //$log.log('Peding state updated to:' + pendingState.name );
        //$urlRouter.sync();
      }

      if (fromState.name == 'login' && Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        $log.log('Ui-router: going from login');
        //$state.go(fromState.name);
        $timeout(function(){
          // $state.go('home', null, {/*reload: true, location: 'replace'*/});
          $state.go('browse-machine');
          //$urlRouter.sync();
        },2000)
      }



      $log.log({
        'toState': toState,
        'toParams': toParams,
        'fromState': fromState,
        'fromParams': fromParams
      })

    })


    return {

    };
  });
```

Comment: Hello, Could you show what th log says in your web console ?

Comment: actually it doesn't return any error. 
i just used $log.log(toState, fromState) inside the event handler to output the object. That's when i noticed that event.preventDefault() followed by a $state.go('stateName') was causing an infinit loop because i saw the log mesage printed undreads of times

Comment: for example, in my sample code, if i try to access a page coming from a state named 'login' i would see 'Ui-router: going from login' print undread of times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general I would say, let's redirect *(`$state.go()`)* **only if needed**. In other cases, get out from the event listener:

```
if (toState.name === 'login' ){
  // doe she/he try to go to login? - let him/her go
  return;
}

if(Auth.isLoggedIn()){
   // is logged in? - can go anyhwere
   return;
}

// else
$state.go('login')
```

This is simplified logic, but shows, that we should change to execution only if needed. There are some other examles with more detailed implementation and plunkers:

- [Confusing $locationChangeSuccess and $stateChangeStart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25872219/1679310)
- [Angular UI Router: nested states for home to differentiate logged in and logged out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25191768/1679310)
- [other example of log in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25029935/1679310)
- [angular ui-router login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22537311/1679310)

As provided in the comment, there was [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jnz2JN?p=preview), which I changed like this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XmDmTc?p=preview)

```
...
// three new lines
if (toState.name === 'specialRoute'){
  return;
}

if (fromState.name=='route1'){
  event.preventDefault();
  $state.go('specialRoute')
}
```

And this is **not** looping anymore. Please, check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XmDmTc?p=preview)

Comment: please take a look at this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview. Open the terminal to see the infinite loop that i was talking about

Comment: I tried to show how to ... in a fork, and updated the answer. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, it seems to fix the problem, but what was cauzing the infinite loop?

Comment: The point is, that we firstly should solve: "is it already redirected?" I.e.: was already trying to reach the state `'specialRoute'`? And if yes... then just return.. let UI-Router to continue. And that was missing. So after redirect was triggered firstly then **again and again and again...** now it is checked... and if `'specailRoute'` is already selected... no other redirect! Does it help?

Comment: Great to see that, Enjoy amazing `UI-Router`, sir ;) ;)

Comment: Thats a great hack

Answer (score 8):

You should use the notify option :

```
$state.go('your.state',{ your params },{notify: false});
```

This will prevent stateChangeStart to fire again.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, but now it does not transition to the toState.

Answer (score 6):

This answer helped me:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise( function($injector, $location) {
            var $state = $injector.get("$state");
            $state.go("app.home");
        });
```

Original:
[Why does AngularJS with ui-router keep firing the $stateChangeStart event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065699/why-does-angularjs-with-ui-router-keep-firing-the-statechangestart-event)

Answer (score 1):

I simply used `$location.path('every/where')` instead of `$state.go('every/where')`

:) .

Comment: Minor issue with using $location inside of $stateChangeStart:  the state you wanted to avoid will start loading and possibly displaying before the redirect happens.

Answer (score 1):

The infinite loop is partly caused by

```
if (toState.name == 'login' ...) { $state.go('login'); ...
```

..which says `if` you're going to the login state, `then` go to the login state.

...And  calling `event.preventDefault()` as the first line in the event handler doesn't help.  When you use `go()` to go to the login screen (or anywhere else), that state change is *also* prevented by `event.preventDefault()`.  It should only be used within an `if`.

Your entire $stateChangeStart handler should instead be...

```
if (!Auth.isLoggedIn() && toState.name != 'login') {
    event.preventDefault();
    Auth.desiredState = toState.name;
    $state.go('login');
}
```

...which reads naturally. "`If` you're not logged in and you're not already going to the login screen, `then` stop what you're doing, I'll remember where you wanted to go, and you now go to the login screen."

Later your `Auth` object will issue a `$state.go(Auth.desiredState)` when it's satisfied with the user.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me,  Below code helps to get rid of infinite loop

```
  let firstPass = true;
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
    if ($scope.addForm.$dirty && firstPass) {
      event.preventDefault();
      ConfirmationDialog.openNavigateAwayConfirmationModal().then(function () {
        firstPass = false;
        return $state.go(toState, toParams);
      });
      firstPass = true;
    }
  });
```