# AngularJS and ui-router sign in: max iteration reached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS application with UI-Router. In my `app.js` file I have the following code (where AuthFact is a custom factory for authentication utility):

```
var testapp = angular.module('testapp', ['ui.router']);

testapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/products');

   $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'Views/App.html',
    })
    .state('app.products', {
        url: '/products',
        templateUrl: 'Views/Product/Product.html',
        controller: 'ProductController',
        authenticate: true
    })
    .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'Views/Login.html',
    authenticate: false
    })
});

testapp.run(function ($rootScope, $state, AuthFact) {
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", 
   function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (!AuthFact.IsAuthenticated() && toState.authenticate == true) {
        $state.go('login');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

When I run my application, it tries to go to the `/products` url because the otherwise route, but because the user isn't logged it redirect to the `/login` page.

The problem is that i have the following error:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

Comment: Safe to assume that the `login` state has `authenticate: false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem too and here's how we fixed it...

First, the `otherwise` rule. You'll want to be directed to the right URL based on the authenticated state. To get the `AuthFact` in the `config`, you can use the function version of `otherwise` which is passed the `$injector`...

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector) {
    var AuthFact = $injector.get('AuthFact');
    return AuthFact.IsAuthenticated() ? '/app/products' : '/login';
});
```

And then for your state change listener...

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
    if (toState.authenticate && !AuthFact.IsAuthenticated()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

---

Rather than adding top-level properties to your state configs (such as `authenticate`), you should probably use the `data` property, eg

```
data: {
    authenticate: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the fact, that if we go to Login ... we still do redirect. Adjust the listener like this

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", 
  function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    // if already redirected - GET OUT
    if(toState.name === "login"){
      return; // no redirect anymore.. 
    }

    // this condition could be true even if going to login...
    if (!AuthFact.IsAuthenticated() && toState.authenticate == true) {
        $state.go('login');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Similar issue

- [Angular infinite digest loop with ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28226486/1679310)
- [Ui-Router $state.go inside $on('$stateChangeStart') is cauzing an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26796945/1679310)