# 10 $digest() iterations reached error in ionic(angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am writing my first app in angularjs and it gives me error

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at ionic.bundle.js:8890
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:23108)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23333)
    at bootstrapApply (ionic.bundle.js:10275)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:13012)
    at doBootstrap (ionic.bundle.js:10273)
    at bootstrap (ionic.bundle.js:10293)
    at angularInit (ionic.bundle.js:10187)
    at ionic.bundle.js:34952
    at HTMLDocument.trigger (ionic.bundle.js:11571)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:20434
ionic.bundle.js:23336 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
ionic.bundle.js:20434 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at ionic.bundle.js:8890
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:23108)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23333)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:18486)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:18676)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:18617)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:20434
ionic.bundle.js:23336 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

My culprit app.js code is

```
run(function ($rootScope, $state, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event,next, nextParams, fromState) {

    if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
      if (next.name !== 'app.login') {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('app.login');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

If I remove the last part of redirecting user to login page if he is not authenticated, I dont get the error. During the bootup it indeed gets into the loop multiple times if I start with

```
domain.com/
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Yes but I dont see the reason to loop infinite times here!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does AngularJS with ui-router keep firing the $stateChangeStart event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065699/why-does-angularjs-with-ui-router-keep-firing-the-statechangestart-event)

Comment: need to see the ui-route code to make sense of this

Comment: I solved it and it's similar to above link

Comment: Please either post the solution or a link to the solution and accept the answer. I'm having this same problem and google linked me to this unresolved question.